# unity for mac doesnt have GetGraphicsAPIs

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this error for compiling source on Android or iOS

`UnityEditor.PlayerSettings' does not contain a definition for`GetGraphicsAPIs'

Howvere I tried the same code on windows8 unity 5, it works properly.

In short

```
Unity5Mac Android                 error
Unity5Mac iOS                     error
Unity5Mac pc,mac,linux standalone OK
Unity5Win Android                 OK
Unity5Win iOS                     OK
Unity5Win pc,mac,linux standalone OK
```

I have googled GetGraphicsAPIs and check the document about unity5.

Could anyone know some information??

Comment: Are you using the same Unity versions on Mac and Windows? I think this GetGraphicsAPI stuff was only introduced in 5.1.1 or so, so you may want to check if you really have the same Unity version.

Comment: THanks jan my unity in mac was 5.0.2. I upgraded and solved.